# How can I remove the order title on the order page totaly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how can I remove the page title on the order page totaly? I know I can remove it with display: none; but I want to remove it totaly like with a hook but I can't find a hook for this. Is there a pro outsite?

The HTML: `<h1 class="entry-title main_title">Bestellnummer 390</h1>`

I just want it to remove on the order page. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear at all, don't use images in the posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add an id="entry_title" to the html element of the order page? and then target the id with display:none. If so this will only hide the heading of the order page.

```
<h1 id="entry_title" class="entry-title main_title">Bestellnummer 390</h1>
```

stylesheet

```
#entry_title{
display:none;
}
```